# Jquery and HTML FormData returns "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, upload

I'm using this script to upload my image files: http://jsfiddle.net/eHmSr/

```
$('.uploader input:file').on('change', function() {
  $this = $(this);

  $('.alert').remove();

  $.each($this[0].files, function(key, file) {
    $('.files').append('<li>' + file.name + '</li>');

    data = new FormData();
    data.append(file.name, file);

    $.ajax({
      url: $('.uploader').attr('action'),
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: data
    });
  });
});
```

But when I click in upload button, the JavaScript console returns this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

[image: jQuery Error]

Can you help me?

Comment: Are you sure about this? `dataType: 'json',`???

Comment: Yes, the URL will return in this format.

Comment: In my case, I wanted to submit a file as part of a larger set of data to a .NET MVC Controller that accepted a serialized object as the parameter to its action. It was necessary to use a FormData object, as suggested by [lilalinux](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410212/lilalinux), as well as `processData: false`, as suggested by [Blender](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464744/blender), *and also* `contentType: false`, as suggested by [Caio Tarifa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/977687/caio-tarifa). Anything less than *all three* did not work. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3

Answer (score 179, accepted):

jQuery processes the `data` attribute and converts the values into strings.

[Adding `processData: false`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to your options object fixes the error, but I'm not sure if it fixes the problem.

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/eHmSr/1/**

Comment: Thanks, but I need to remove this property, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431760/html5-formdata-file-upload-with-rubyonrails.

Comment: I fix it, just adding `contentType: false`. Thanks again!

Comment: @Blender This same code is working in my system but not in my friends(both are using windows 10) ,file is not getting posted.No error in console.

Comment: In my case the problem was, that I used var data = {}; However, you must use var data = new FormData();

Comment: I couldn't figure out why this wasn't working... until I realized that process is spelled with one `c`, not two.

Comment: @Yaakov's comment might not be the right answer but this saved me a serious headache. After trying a whole lot of options, I realized that `processData` was misspelled as processDat*e* 

Answer (score 22):

I had the same problem

I fixed that by using two options

```
contentType: false
processData: false
```

Actually I Added these two command to my $.ajax({}) function

Comment: Can these be used with $.post? if so how??

Answer (score 8):

Adding `processData: false` to the `$.ajax` options will fix this issue.

Answer (score 3):

My experience:

```
  var text = $('#myInputField');  
  var myObj = {title: 'Some title', content: text};  
  $.post(myUrl, myObj, callback);
```

The problem is that I forgot to add .val() to the end of $('#myInputField'); this action makes me waste time trying to figure out what was wrong, ***causing Illegal Invocation Error***, since $('#myInputField') was in a different file than that system pointed out incorrect code. Hope this answer help fellows in the same mistake to avoid to loose time.

Answer (score -2):

In my case, there was a mistake in the list of the parameters was not well formed.
So make sure the parameters are well formed.
For e.g. correct format of parameters

```
data: {'reporter': reporter,'partner': partner,'product': product}
```