# Posting an image using a jQuery AJAX call to an MVC action

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

```
$("#preview").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Preview")',
        data: {
            color: $("#color-picker").val(),
            logo: $("#fileInput")[0].files[0]
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success!");
        },
        dataType: "json"
    });
});
```

Which uses this element:

```
<input id="fileInput" type="file" />
```

Which tries to post an image to this MVC action:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Preview(string color, HttpPostedFileBase logo)
{
    return Json("Success.");
}
```

Unfortunately, when I post, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` in Chrome's logs. This error comes from the jQuery side of things according to the stack trace. There's nothing wrong with `$("#color-picker").val()` nor with `$("#fileInput")[0].files[0]` when I check them in Chrome Developer Tools' watch before the call happens (one is a `string` with the appropriate color code, the other is a `File`).

I did troubleshoot it to find the reason why this happens. It is because I try to pass `$("#fileInput")[0].files[0]` as a parameter, but I get the same error when I try to do it [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2428296/jquery-ajax-upload-file-in-asp-net-mvc) by appending the file. I am using the latest version of Chrome and I've been researching into a way to pass an image quite a bit. I have been checking lots of questions on Stack Overflow to try to find a solution but so far I could not find a good way to upload this file.

Does anyone know what kind of security concern causes file uploads to not be allowed like this and how I can upload an image in a similar fashion, or by what means I will have to do so? What alternatives are there? I can't seem to make anything work so far that I've come across on Stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do something like this
in javascript

```
var fd = new FormData();
var files = $("#fileInput").get(0).files;

if(files.lenght > 0){
   fd.append("logo",files[0]);
}

$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("Preview")',
        data:fd,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("Success!");
        }
    });
```

on controller you can get image like this

```
if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.AllKeys.Any())
{
   var picture = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["logo"];
}
```

Comment: I tried it like this too (in my question I pointed that out), but this gives me illegal invocation errors as well!

Comment: My pardons, I see you added two different parameters (processData/contentType as false) to the AJAX call. I will try it with those in a bit as I think that's the trick or at least part of it! Source: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755945/jquery-and-html-formdata-returns-uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation

Comment: by default Jquery use application/x-www-form-urlencoded has contentType by setting to false you wil send via XMLHttpRequest basically you can use System.Web Request to get value

Comment: about the processData not sure but i remember that if you use FormData ocject you should turn off i think you tell him not to modify my data when sending

Comment: Yes, both must be set! Thanks!