# I am not able to save image in asp.net mvc5 with json

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My file upload is not working. I want to upload images.
I have already created the input type file in my view. 
 Here is my code-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddOrEdit(tbl_employee emp)
{
    var getGender = db.tbl_gender.ToList();
    SelectList list = new SelectList(getGender, "gender_type", "gender_type", emp);
    ViewBag.genderList = list;

    if (emp.employee_image != null)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(emp.imageFile.FileName);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(emp.imageFile.FileName);
        fileName = fileName + extension;
        emp.employee_image = "~/Images/Employee/" + fileName;
        fileName = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/Employee/"), fileName);
        emp.imageFile.SaveAs(fileName); 
    }
    if (emp.employee_id == 0)
    {
        db.tbl_employee.Add(emp);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Saved Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        db.Entry(emp).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(new { success = true, message = "Updated Successfully" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }     
}
```

Here is my `tbl_employee.cs`

```
public long employee_id { get; set; }
public string employee_image { get; set; }
public HttpPostedFileBase imageFile { get; set; }
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Not clear what your asking here. Your data model cannot contain a `HttpPostedFileBase` property (there is no database equivalent for that) - you store the path of the file in the database.

Comment: Yes my employee_image property is the property to save path.

Comment: What is your issue?? You didt mentioned that.

Comment: And why are you checking `if (emp.employee_image != null)` - that would always be `null` for a new employee so your image would never be saved.

Comment: Image is not uploading. It's going null in database.

Comment: Image is not uploading. Its putting null value in database

Comment: If you want to save image in your database, you can use byte array type

Comment: Add `HttpPostedFileBase Image` for getting uploaded file in controller.

Comment: There is a solution here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32336556/posting-an-image-using-a-jquery-ajax-call-to-an-mvc-action. I think it may be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Include `HttpPostedFileBase` in your function for getting the uploaded file in your `AddOrEdit` function.

```
public ActionResult AddOrEdit(tbl_employee emp, HttpPostedFileBase Image)
{

}
```

For more explanation, include also the `view` with your question.
Ensure your view contain code for image upload.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrEdit", "Employee", null, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
```

Comment: I want to save the imageFile location in my database and retrieve the image in the index view. I am using jquery and ajax for POST method. I think that's the reason my image is not uploading via normal way.

Comment: Do you get value of uploaded file in controller?