# ReactJS Ajax File Upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload, reactjs

I'm trying to upload a file with React but am unsure of the best way to do so. I'm trying to store the file on change but that doesn't appear to be working. I'm currently getting the error `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` on submit.

Is there a better approach to uploading files with React?

---

File change & upload functions:

```
changeFile: function(e) {
            this.setState({csvFile: e.target.files[0]});
        },

importFile: function() {
            data = new FormData();
            data.append('file', this.state.csvFile);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/csv/import",
                data: data,
                dataType: "JSON"
            }).done(function(json){
                alert("hooray!");
            });
        },
```

JSX:

```
    <div>
        <input type="file" onChange={this.changeFile}/>
        <button onClick={this.importFile}>Import</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use react-file-uploader https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-file-uploader

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ugh, turns out I just needed to add the following to my ajax call:

```
processData: false,
contentType: false
```

OR

```
importFile: function() {
            data = new FormData();
            data.append('file', this.state.csvFile);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/csv/import",
                data: data,
                dataType: "JSON",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false
            }).done(function(json){
                alert("hooray!");
            });
        },
```

Answer (score 1):

The setState is an async function, so you cant get state immediately.
You can try with callback to check your file.

```
this.setState({
  ...
}, function(){
  ...
  console.log(...);
});
```

ref: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

Comment: Thanks, but this creates a new problem on submit: `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`

Comment: It's a jQuery error. use formdata or jQuery config.
see

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755945/jquery-and-html-formdata-returns-uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation