# IllegalInvocation when sending POST request with File

Tags: javascript, jquery, imgur

I have an HTML5 File object retrieved from an `<input />` tag. I'm trying to upload it to imgur.com, an online photo sharing service. However, whenever I send the following post request, I get an IllegalInvocation error.

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('image', file);
fd.append('key', 'MY_KEY');
$.post('https://api.imgur.com/3/image', fd, function(result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

I've checked the `file` that I'm sending and it's a regular object:

`File {name: "cloud.png", lastModified: 1456036658039, lastModifiedDate: Sat Feb 20 2016 22:37:38 GMT-0800 (PST), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 721366…}...`

EDIT: New request gives 400 *Bad Request*

```
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('image', file);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Client-ID MY_CLIENT_ID'
        },
        url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
        processData: false,
        data: fd,
        success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Tried with `processData: false`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755945/jquery-and-html-formdata-returns-uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation/12756023#12756023

Comment: Hey, thanks. I guess I can't send the `processData` option using the shorthand AJAX. I tried sending the updated request using the full `$.ajax` syntax and I'm getting a `https://api.imgur.com/3/image 400 (Bad Request)`