# Illegal invocation error on formData Append

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am appending a Javascript object and a file to a formData like this :

```
myFormData.append('myJSObject', JSON.stringify(myObject));

 var myFile = document.getElementById('myinput').files[0];
    myFormData.append('myfile', myFile);
```

When I make AJAX call like this :

```
                    $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/SomeController",
                    async:false,
                    data: myFormData,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
```

I get Illegal Invocation error. How should I append files to formData so that I can avoid this error? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery and HTML FormData returns "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755945/jquery-and-html-formdata-returns-uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation)

Comment: In short: add "processData: false", "contentType: false" to your ajax object to avoid throwing the illegal invocation error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without json content type and processData:

```
var myFile = document.getElementById('myinput').files[0];
    myFormData.append('myfile', myFile);

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/SomeController",
   async:false,
   data: myFormData,
   contentType: false,
   processData: false
});
```