# jQuery.get with data creates url with [object%20object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a GET request using jQuery. Instead of jquery appending my data name/vale pairs to the end of my url, it is appending `[object%20object]`.

I am using both the `$.ajax` and `$.get` functions. See [$.ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and [$.get](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

In researching this issue, I have found [suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755945/jquery-and-html-formdata-returns-uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation) to add `processData: false` and `contentType: false` to my settings object (which shouldn't matter), but these options do not fix my problem.

Can someone confirm that this is a bug? Could my endpoint be blocking my request? But if so, why would that affect the url params?

here is my code that I am trying.

### HTML

```
<input name='email'/> <button class='btn-submit'>Submit</button>
```

### JS

```
$('.btn-submit').click(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();

     var email = $('[name=email]').val();
     var data = {
       "apitoken": 'MYTOKEN',
       "listid": 1111,
       "email": email
     };
     var endpoint = "https://myendpoint.com/";
     $.ajax({
         url: endpoint,
         method: 'GET',
         processData: false,
         contentType: false,
         data: data,
         success: function (data, status, jqxhr) {
             console.log('success', data, status);
         },
         error: function(jqxhr, status) {
             console.log('error', jqxhr, status);
         }
     });

     // THIS IS THE GET METHOD
     $.get(endpoint, data, function(data, status, jqxhr) { console.log('success', data, status); });
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/ajax "
processData (default: true)
Type: Boolean
By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded". If you want to send a DOMDocument, or other non-processed data, set this option to false.
"

Comment: You don't want processData to be false.  You *want* jQuery to turn your object into a query string.

Comment: Get rid of the processData and contentType settings of false, and it makes the ajax request properly.  So if you were seeing an error before putting those properties in there, then it would be helpful if we could see that version of the code that was having issues.

Comment: @Taplar Hey thats it. thanks. I feel like an idiot, thanks for clarifying..... Initially I tried a basic get statement and encountered an 'illegal innvocation' error, which pushed me down a worm hole and caused me to fiddle with the processdata option.... I am guessing a syntax triggered the original illegal innvocation error