# How to upload with other parameters on jQuery&Javascript Mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, model-view-controller

With the help of an input, I want to upload photos using the ajaxPost method. The code you tried is as follows.

HTML;

```
<input type="file" class="form-control" id="update-category-photo" accept=".jpg,.png,.gif,.JPEG,.JPG" />
```

Javascript;

```
    function updateCategory() {
            var fileUpload = $("#update-category-photo").get(0);
            var files = fileUpload.files;
    
            var formData = new FormData();
    
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                formData.append('categoryImage', files[i]);
            }
    
   postAjax("/Admin/Category/UpdateCategory", {
            categoryName: $("#update-category-name").val(),
            categoryId: $("#update-category-id").val(),
             formData
        } , function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        });
        }
```

And base:> Admin/Category Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult UpdateCategory(int categoryId, string categoryName)
        {
            return Json("ok:" + Request.Files.Count, 0);//just test now
        }
```

When I just want to post, I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation".

Comment: I dont think you are following the parameters correctly. There are two params catid and catname while you are passing an object from ajax.

Comment: I was try it

  postAjax("/Admin/Category/UpdateCategory", {
            categoryName: $("#update-category-name").val(),
            categoryId: $("#update-category-id").val(),
            categoryPhoto: formData
        } , function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        });

Comment: You already has an object. IN your .net just provide params as object

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/a/12756023/7629020 ?

Answer (score 1):

this answer;

```
var file = $("#update-category-photo").get(0).files;

        var data = new FormData();

        data.append("CategoryPhoto", file[0]);
        data.append("CategoryId", $("#update-category-id").val());
        data.append("CategoryName", $("#update-category-name").val());

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Admin/Category/UpdateCategory',
            data: data,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
```

And use ViewModel on controller action