# 'Illegal invocation' error when trying to upload file with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Trying to upload a file via ajax but I keep getting 'Illegal invocation' error when I try to pass through the file. All other input fields get passed without a problem (if I comment out the file).

Cut down version of my code:

```
    let file = $('.file-upload')[0];
    let form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', file.files[0]);


    let data = {
        action: 'update_settings',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        'submit': true,
        'username': $('input[name="username"]').val(),
        'email': $('input[name="email"]').val(),
        'file': form_data,
    };

    
    $.post(url, data, function(response) {
                
     
    });
```

Cut down HTML:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input class="file-upload" type="file" name="file" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Also, uploading the file without ajax works just fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jquery and HTML FormData returns "Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755945/jquery-and-html-formdata-returns-uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation)

Comment: @ericmp sadly no, I had already tried solutions in that post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not invoking the ajax correctly.
should be

```
let data = {
  // action: 'update_settings',
  processData: false,
  contentType: false,
  // 'submit': true,
  // 'username': $('input[name="username"]').val(),
  // 'email': $('input[name="email"]').val(),
  'data': form_data, // <-----
};
```

Also you should add the other params (username, email, action, submit) inside the formData object as well:

```
formData.append("action", 'update_settings');
// and so on
```

Not tested... but something along those lines.